# How to create Search Box cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I'm new in CakePHP... I want to create search box dynamically in my view page without using plugins.

```
<div class="box-tools">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
        <input type="text" name="table_search" class="form-control pull-right" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're going to have to use the Formhelper provided by CakePHP.
Since you are using Bootstrap which requires specific div's and classes on your input fields/containers, you could use something like the following:

```
<?=$this->Form->create('Yourmodel')?>
<div class="box-tools">
    <div class="input-group input-group-sm" style="width: 150px;">
        <?=$this->Form->input('table_search', array('placeholder' => 'Search', 'class' => 'form-control pull-right', 'type' => 'text', 'div' => false, 'label' => false))?>
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <?=$this->Form->submit('<i class="fa fa-search"></i>', array('escape' => false, 'class' => 'btn btn-default', 'div' => false))?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?=$this->Form->end()?>
```